# Yup validation, do not show error message for form field

Tags: material-ui, formik, yup

I use `Yup` along with `Formik` and `Material UI` for validating a form field.

What I want to achieve here is, I only want to show the error message if the first test fails ie. for duplicate code.
For the second test, if it fails there should not be any error message under the field, but the field should be highlighted as an error field.

But if I remove 'validCode' from the arguments of the second test the field will not be highlighted as an error field.

```
const YUP_STRING = Yup.string().ensure().trim();

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
   code: YUP_STRING.test(
    '',
    'duplicateCode',
    code => code !== prohibitedCode
  ).test('', 'validCode', code => codeValidator.validate(code));
});
```

I want to achieve this,

[image]

but what I have now is,

[image]

Is there any way that I can achieve something like the first picture using Yup?

Comment: can you provide a sandbox with minimal reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer but, You are leaving error name field name empty, which is why it's validating the error but can't find the message,

```
date: YUP_STRING.test("duplicateCodeErrorName","duplicateCode",
function (value) {
 code => code !== prohibitedCode
  ).test('validCodeErrorName', 'validCode', code => codeValidator.validate(code));
})
```

This how I do regularly,

```
date: Yup.date().test(
"noSunday", "You Can't select Sunday as Additional Holiday",
function (value) {
const day = moment(value).day();
return day !== 0 ? true : false;
   })
```